# Finding limit of a 2 variable function (or show a lack of)

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

$$ \lim_{x,y\to -1,0} \frac{πx^4 - 3xy^3}{ln(x^4+y^4)} $$

How do i find the following limit, or explain that it does not exist?

Comment: Do you have a guess?

Answer (score 1):

Let $r(x,y) = πx^4 - 3xy^2$ be the nominator and $s(x,y) = \log (x^4 + y^4)$ be the denominator.

Now find a sequence $(p_n)_n ∈ ℕ$ in $ℝ^2$ such that

- $p_n \overset{n → ∞}\longrightarrow (-1,0)$,
- $r(p_n)\overset{n → ∞}\longrightarrow π$, and
- $s(p_n) \overset{n → ∞}\longrightarrow 0$.

Then conclude.